# Override variadic function

Tags: c#, overriding, abstract, variadic

I'm having trouble to override a variatic function. Examples worth better than words, let's take an example :

Here's my abstract class :

```
public abstract class MyClass<T> {
    public abstract T DoSomething(params Object[] objs);
    public void ShowSomething(List<T> items){
        foreach(T it in items){
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1},{2}",it.propA,it.propB,it.propC));
        }
    }
    // Other things 
}
```

And here's my attempt to override it :

```
public class MyOverridenClass : MyClass<MyType> {
    public override MyType DoSomething(int a, int b, string c){
        return new MyType(){ propA = a+b, propB = a-b, propC = c+""+a};
     }
}
```

And from my main :

```
public static void Main(string[] args){
    MyOverridenClass cl = new MyOverridenClass();
    List<MyType> lst = new List<MyType>();
    lst.Add(cl.DoSomething(1,2,"foo"));
    cl.ShowSomething();
}
```

I expect it to output :

```
3,-1,foo1
```

But when I compile, I have an error saying that no suitable method was found to override for DoSomething(int, int, string).

Is it even possible or do I have to find a workaround ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DoSomething` in `MyOverriddenClass` can't override `DoSomething(params Object[] objs)` because you can't override a variadic function with a non-variadic one.

The trivial answer to why not is because the spec says so. But in an imagined language that is not C# this still wouldn't work, because the implementing method is less specific than the base method, violating the contract.

In C# the signatures have to match exactly when overriding, but this is not needed for correctness. For correctness it is sufficient that a method implements the contract.

For example, this is a base class, that returns something of type Base, and takes an object as a parameter.

```
public class Base {
  public Base example(TParam obj)
}
```

If we were to override example, we need it to be more specific to be correct

```
public class Derived : Base { 
  override public TReturn example(TParam2 obj) //this is illegal in C#
}
```

C# requires `TReturn` == `Base` and `TParam` == `TParam2`. Meanwhile, correctness requires something less strict. It only requires that `TReturn : Base`, and that `TParam : TParam2` (note that they are flipped)

To see why, take for example

```
Base b = new Derived()
Base newbase = d.example(default(TParam))
```

It must return a value that will "fit" in `Base`. It also most take any parameter that can be fed to `Base.example`. If it takes more specific parameters, then you're hosed, because the compiler doesn't know (and can't know and *shouldn't* know) that `b` is of type `Derived`.

Now back to variadic methods. It's conceivable that some language that is not C# but sort of looks like it does allow this. It's just as conceivable that such a language that is not C# it has some syntactic sugar for decomposing a variadic method and the following can be convered back and forth:

```
public T Example(params object[] objs)

public T Example2(object obj1, object obj2)
```

but an implementation in a derived type should always be *less specific* in it's parameter list, not more specific. So the best this (non-C#) language could do is allow you to override, for example,

```
public T Example(params SpecificType[] values)
```

with

```
public T Example(params object[] objs)
```

or

```
public T Example2(object obj1, object obj2)
```

but never the other way around.

tl;dr:

The language doesn't allow this, and couldn't allow this because it would break the substitution principle.

Answer (score 3):

When you override a method, the signature must be the same. You can't "invent" a new signature.

```
public override MyType DoSomething(params Object[] objs)
{
    // do something
}
```

There is nothing you can do here...

So you have to decide what signature you want your method to have, and use it. You could even keep both signatures in the `MyClass<T>`